# How to collect the method names that uses receiver variable of one method as arguments

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, data-mining, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I want to get all the method names that uses a methods receiver variable as an argument. For example:

```
Fl fl = new Fl(X);
X.getAddress();
X.getName();
```

Here the receiver variable X that is used as an argument for the method Fl. So the answer would show Fl.
I can read the names of methods that has a receiver variable but don't know how to read the methods that uses the variable as argument. I am new in AST jdt. This is what I have tried

```
    @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodInvocation node) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            MethodInvocation mi =  (MethodInvocation) node;
            System.out.println("Receiver Variable: "+node.getExpression());
            
            return true;
        }
```